# Multiple messages per poll in wsDualHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, binding, wsdualhttpbinding

The Polling duplex binding supports multiple messages per poll.

```
<pollingDuplex duplexMode="MultipleMessagesPerPoll"
```

However, pollingDuplex is not supported for non-silverlight clients. So I have to use `wsDualHttpBinding` with my WPF client.

Is there a way to send multiple messages per poll in `wsDualHttpBinding`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wsDualHttpBinding doesn't use polling - in fact the only duplex binding that does is 
PollingDuplex.

All of the other duplex bindings send the message directly to the client - they work slightly differently to eachother (wsDualHttpBinding has a second connection from the server to the client whereas NetTcpBinding uses a single connection from client to service and the service sends messages back along this same connection)

If you want to batch up notifications in the server for less round trips then you would have to write that batching